# How to dynamically pause videos when parent Bootstrap Collapse panel is collapsed?

Tags: jquery, video, twitter-bootstrap-3, mediaelement.js

I am building a website prototype using Boostrap 3. I have a column of videos that are displayed using the Collapse component. The videos are being displayed using mediaelementjs.

When a panel within the Collapse panel group is expanded, the video become visible and the user can play the video. But when the panel is collapsed, the video continues to play.

I would like for the video to pause when the panel is collapsed.

I have this working for the first panel, #collapseOne, but I'm stuck on how to get the code working for any and all panels found within the site.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtowle/rsx80tcu/1/) I have with the code that I have working thus far...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Initialize MediaElement - video player  
$('video').mediaelementplayer();

// Start video on panel show
$('#collapseOne').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('video').each(function(){this.player.pause()});
})

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace `panel-collapse` with the class of your element if different:

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel-collapse').each(function (k, v) {
        $video = $(v).find('video');
        var player = new MediaElementPlayer($video);
        $(v).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            player.pause();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I tried dropping both solutions in place of the code I had and neither work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? `panel-collapse` is the correct class.

Comment: Ah i see you can't use the player like that... sec I will update answer